# Trying to find a book from the 1960s about people living in an asteroid in multiple spheres

Tags: story-identification

I’m trying to find a book to surprise my boyfriend.  He loved it as a 6th grader in the mid 1960s.  It was about people who lived inside a sphere in an  asteroid but did’t realize they weren’t on a planet. And there were other “spheres” in the asteroid as well.   That’s all he remembers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I understand you want to surprise him, but it might be more useful to engage him in your search.  He might remember other helpful details, like the cover art, how long it was, names of characters or places...  You're sure it was an asteroid the people were living in, and not a spaceship?

Comment: If he had access to it as a 6th grader in the 1960's, it could have been SBS or a short story in a magazine.

Comment: It might be Brian Aldiss' 1958 novel *Non-Stop*. It doesn't take place in an asteroid, but in what is ultimately revealed to be a generation spaceship. The spaceship is modular, and it is possible that the modules are spherical - I can't remember, as I haven't read it since the 1970s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Stop_(novel)

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen That's what I was alluding to, yes. ;)

Comment: There were several generation-ship novels in that era and my guess would be Captive Universe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_Universe, it doesn't fit the multiple spheres but there were different compartments within the asteroid.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be  [*STRIKEBREAKER*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikebreaker_(short_story)) by Asimov ?

It is a long shot, because the people know very well **where** they live.

One point that matches your boyfriend's memories is that nobody lives on the **surface** of the asteroid (or rather, planetoid). The colonists have dug many concentric spheres inside the planetoid, and this is where they live.

> The world of Elsevere is an extrasolar planetoid a hundred miles in diameter. It is home to an insular, idiosyncratic human colony of thirty thousand people, who have inhabited the planet in all three dimensions.

The relevant point here is "in all three dimensions". It is clearly stated in the story that the colonists have dug, and keep digging concentric levels inside the planetoid.

The other point that matches is the publication date, 1957, so he might well have read it in the mid-60's.
And I also was a 6th grader around that time, when I read it, and I liked it a lot, so....

And I also had forgotten the name, and asked about it on this forum, and got the answer. So if it is the same story, there would be duplication.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to correctly use the "add hyperlink" tool. Could someone help ? Anyway, by copying the link I wrote and pasting it in one's navigator, one does get a descxription of the story.

Comment: That should cover the hyperlink.  :)

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon Thanks !

Comment: FWIW, you asked about it [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221635/), but the dupe target would be [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/197586/23243).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yes, I remembered that my question was already a dupe of the older one, this is why I used the phrase "there would be duplication", which is ambiguous enough to cover the exact situation, rather than "it would be a duplicate of my question".

Comment: :) As much as anything, I just wanted to put the URLs out there so that the sidebar would catch them. It can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

*[The World and Thorinn](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1171823.The_World_and_Thorinn)* by Damon Knight is possible.

> Thorinn, alienated from his father and brothers, embarks on a journey to the center of the earth, traveling down a dry well and encountering strange worlds, a variety of races, and finally, a supreme intelligence.

Thorin's initial world is in a "basin" where the edges of the world reach up into the sky. He encounters multiple other worlds with different races, all with the same design (because they are also small worlds carved out of Earth). It's a bit late, with the original stories published in 1968 and the fixup book compiling and stitching them together not coming out until 1981.

FWIW, the bit that stuck with me from the book ([I asked about it before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55178/23243)) was him encountering a situation near the end where he fell for a prolonged amount of time toward the center of the Earth, enough time to eat, relieve himself, and try to sleep.